# how it prints: 11 21 31

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void increment_all (int* start, int* stop)
{
  int * current = start;
  while (current != stop) {
    ++(*current);  // increment value pointed
    ++current;     // increment pointer
  }
}

void print_all (const int* start, const int* stop)
{
  const int * current = start;
  while (current != stop) {
    cout << *current << endl;
    ++current;     // increment pointer
  }
}

int main ()
{
  int numbers[] = {10,20,30};
  increment_all (numbers,numbers+3);
  print_all (numbers,numbers+3);
  return 0;
}
```

I understand the basics of pointers but i can't figure out how it prints:
11
21
31
If it's possible a step by step explanation of the code, thanks in advance.

Comment: Tell what you do not understand. Does the code look like total gibberish or are there some parts that you do have slight idea what it means?

Answer (score 0):

`increment_all` will take 2 pointers as parameters, both of which are pointing to an array. When `increment_all` runs, it's going to loop through the entire array and add 1 to each element.

You can control how far it loops with the second parameter, `stop`, so you could also do `increment_all(numbers, numbers+2)` and get an output of `11 21 30`.

I hope this helped you :D

commented code for `increment_all`:

```
void increment_all (int* start, int* stop)
{
  //current declared so that start is not modified in the loop
  int * current = start;

  //loop through the array until stop is reached
  while (current != stop) {
    ++(*current);  // increment the value in the array
    ++current;     // increment the element being changed in the array
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, can i ask you if i have some other inquories.

Comment: Yeah sure! Feel free to ask away :)

Comment: Honestly when I was starting out I didn't even know what a pointer was until a month of learning c++, and even then, they confused the heck out of me! The best advice I can give you is to not give up and continue learning. Knowledge comes with experience, and the only way you can get that is with practice.

Answer (score 0):

It starts with.

```
  int numbers[] = {10,20,30};
```

So, you understand that `numbers` is the address of the array? It is. And `numbers + 3` is the address of one past the array, it points one position past the `30`. This position is considered invalid for access by de referencing a pointer to there.

So to the print function. It is passed the address of the first position of the array and the location one past the `30` of the array. This is a typical range for a container btw, std::vector has a `begin` and an `end` that use the very same values.

I'll make it look a little different.

```
void print_all (const int* start, const int* stop)
{
  for ( ; start != stop; ++start) {
    std::cout << *start << std::endl;
  }
}
```

We don't need to reassign `start` to another variable. So we come into the loop, check if start is equal to stop. If not, print the value at the address. The compiler knows the size a an `int`pointer so will add the proper offset with `++start`. It is not actually 1 but `sizeof(int)`.

When start is equal to stop, the loop ends, it won't print anymore.